# install dpdk with collectd

Tags: dpdk, collectd

Trying to get collectd-5.12.0 work with DPDK 21.11
I followed the docs https://github.com/collectd/collectd/blob/main/docs/BUILD.dpdkstat.md to install collected with custom dpdk installation folder.

```
pkg-config --libs libdpdk
-Wl,--as-needed -L//lib64 -lrte_node -lrte_graph -lrte_flow_classify -lrte_pipeline -lrte_table -lrte_pdump -lrte_port -lrte_fib -lrte_ipsec -lrte_vhost -lrte_stack -lrte_security -lrte_sched -lrte_reorder -lrte_rib -lrte_dmadev -lrte_regexdev -lrte_rawdev -lrte_power -lrte_pcapng -lrte_member -lrte_lpm -lrte_latencystats -lrte_kni -lrte_jobstats -lrte_ip_frag -lrte_gso -lrte_gro -lrte_gpudev -lrte_eventdev -lrte_efd -lrte_distributor -lrte_cryptodev -lrte_compressdev -lrte_cfgfile -lrte_bpf -lrte_bitratestats -lrte_bbdev -lrte_acl -lrte_timer -lrte_hash -lrte_metrics -lrte_cmdline -lrte_pci -lrte_ethdev -lrte_meter -lrte_net -lrte_mbuf -lrte_mempool -lrte_rcu -lrte_ring -lrte_eal -lrte_telemetry -lrte_kvargs


./configure LIBDPDK_LDFLAGS="-L/root/dpdk-21.11/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib64" LIBDPDK_CPPFLAGS="-I/root/dpdk-21.11/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include"
```

However, it's still not being picked up by collected.
Am I missing anything ?

```
Libraries:
    libdpdk . . . . . . . no (symbol 'rte_eal_init' not found)

Modules:
    dpdkevents. . . . . . no
    dpdkstat  . . . . . . no
    dpdk_telemetry. . . . no
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked after installing jansson-devel

Steps followed :

```
1. ./configure LIBDPDK_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64/" LIBDPDK_CPPFLAGS="-I/root/dpdk-21.11/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include"

2. yum install jansson-devel
```

```
 Modules:
    dpdkevents. . . . . . yes
    dpdkstat  . . . . . . yes
    dpdk_telemetry. . . . yes
```